# Unable to send mail in Symfony 1.31

Tags: symfony1, email, swiftmailer

I am trying to send email using the following method in my action class:

```
  public function executeTestnewmail()
  {
    // send an email to the affiliate
    $message = $this->getMailer()->compose(
      array('my_email_address_here' => 'Jobeet Bot'),
      'recipient_address_here',
      'Jobeet affiliate token',
      <<<EOF
Your Jobeet affiliate account has been activated.

Your token is 1.

The Jobeet Bot.
EOF
    );

    $this->getMailer()->send($message);

    $this->redirect('@homepage');
  }
```

The code above is (almost) verbatim (i.e. almost exact) copy of the Jobeet example - yet when I use correct email addresses for the sender and recipient, no mail is sent, instead, it times out.

I get the following error messages in my log file:

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in $(SYMFONY_ROOT_DIR)\lib\log\sfWebDebugLogger.class.php on line 78 Call Stack: 0.0003 66216 1. {main}(

Does this clue suggest anything at all to anyone?
Has anyone actually managed to send an email using SF1.3+ ?

Incidentally, I can send email from my machine with no problem, by simply using the mail() command (with the same sender/receiver address I am using in my Symfony test), so I know that SMTP etc works correctly on my machine

**[Edit]**

The full stack trace is included below:

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in $(SF_ROOT_DIR)\lib\log\sfWebDebugLogger.class.php on line 78 Call Stack: 0.0003 66216 
1.  {main}() $(PROJECT_DIR)\web\frontend_dev.php:0 0.2684 10774096
2.  sfContext->dispatch() $(PROJECT_DIR)\web\frontend_dev.php:13 0.2684 10774240 
3.  sfFrontWebController->dispatch() $(SF_ROOT_DIR)\lib\util\sfContext.class.php:170 0.2691 10795440 
4.  sfController->forward() $(SF_ROOT_DIR)\lib\controller\sfFrontWebController.class.php:48 0.3280 11707400 
5.  sfFilterChain->execute($(SF_ROOT_DIR)\lib\controller\sfController.class.php:235 0.3286 11715304 
6.  sfRenderingFilter->execute() $(SF_ROOT_DIR)\lib\filter\sfFilterChain.class.php:53 0.3286 11715768 
7.  sfFilterChain->execute() $(SF_ROOT_DIR)\lib\filter\sfRenderingFilter.class.php:33 0.3292 11725920 
8.  sfGuardRememberMeFilter->execute() $(SF_ROOT_DIR)\lib\filter\sfFilterChain.class.php:53 0.3292 11727680 
9.  sfFilterChain->execute() $(PROJECT_DIR)\apps\frontend\lib\sfGuardRememberMeFilter.class.php:65 0.3298 11740192 
10. nonMemberCheckFilter->execute() $(SF_ROOT_DIR)\lib\filter\sfFilterChain.class.php:53 0.3299 11742280 
11. sfFilterChain->execute() $(PROJECT_DIR)\apps\frontend\lib\nonMemberCheckFilter.class.php:68 0.3305 11757240 
12. sfCacheFilter->execute() $(SF_ROOT_DIR)\lib\filter\sfFilterChain.class.php:53 0.3426 11776320 
13. sfFilterChain->execute() $(SF_ROOT_DIR)\lib\filter\sfCacheFilter.class.php:65 0.3433 11793568 
14. sfValidationExecutionFilter->execute() $(SF_ROOT_DIR)\lib\filter\sfFilterChain.class.php:53 0.3434 11795872 
15. sfValidationExecutionFilter->handleAction() $(SF_ROOT_DIR)\lib\plugins\sfCompat10Plugin\lib\filter\sfValidationExecutionFilter.class.php:43 0.3600 11796712 
16. sfValidationExecutionFilter->executeAction() $(SF_ROOT_DIR)\lib\plugins\sfCompat10Plugin\lib\filter\sfValidationExecutionFilter.class.php:87 0.3600 11797136 
17. sfActions->execute() (SF_ROOT_DIR)\lib\plugins\sfCompat10Plugin\lib\filter\sfValidationExecutionFilter.class.php:169 0.3608 11820384 
18. homeActions->executeTestnewmail() $(SF_ROOT_DIR)\lib\action\sfActions.class.php:60 0.4796 13858992 
19. sfMailer->send() $(PROJECT_DIR)\apps\frontend\modules\home\actions\actions.class.php:621 0.4797 13859496 
20. Swift_Mailer->send() $(SF_ROOT_DIR)\lib\mailer\sfMailer.class.php:294 0.4797 13860016 
21. Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->start() $(SF_ROOT_DIR)\lib\vendor\swiftmailer\classes\Swift\Mailer.php:74 0.4850 13876104 
22. Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->initialize() $(SF_ROOT_DIR)\lib\vendor\swiftmailer\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php:101 0.4850 13876448 
23. Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->_establishSocketConnection() $(SF_ROOT_DIR)\lib\vendor\swiftmailer\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php:70 0.4850 13877896 
24. fsockopen() $(SF_ROOT_DIR)\lib\vendor\swiftmailer\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php:233 30.4772 13879672
25. sfWebDebugLogger->handlePhpError() $(SF_ROOT_DIR)\lib\log\sfWebDebugLogger.class.php:0
```

My mail configuration as specified in ($PROJECT_DIR)/apps/frontend/config/factories.yml is:

```
# this is commented out because I want to be able to send mails in dev environment
#dev:
#  mailer:
#    param:
#      delivery_strategy: none

  test:
    mailer:
      param:
        delivery_strategy: none


  all:
    mailer:
      class: sfMailer
      param:
        logging:           %SF_LOGGING_ENABLED%
        charset:           %SF_CHARSET%
        delivery_strategy: realtime
        transport:
          class: Swift_SmtpTransport
          param:
            host:       localhost
            port:       25
            encryption: ~
            username:   ~
            password:   ~
```

**[Edit2]**

My php.ini settings (with regards to SMTP) are:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
;SMTP = localhost
SMTP = smtp.my-isp-address-here
smtp_port = 25
```

Comment: Can you provide the next few lines of that stack trace?

Comment: Maybe you can show your email configuration?

Comment: Your own machine is really the SMTP server?

Comment: Felix, not sure I understand your question. I have edited my question to show my php.ini settings for SMTP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have another SMTP configuration in your `php.ini` file as in your `factories.yml`.
In  the first, you provide your ISP as SMTP server and in the later your own machine (`localhost`).  But I guess you don't have a SMTP server on your machine running, thats way it has to be ( I think):

```
 all:
    mailer:
      class: sfMailer
      param:
        logging:           %SF_LOGGING_ENABLED%
        charset:           %SF_CHARSET%
        delivery_strategy: realtime
        transport:
          class: Swift_SmtpTransport
          param:
            host:       smtp.your-isp-address-here
            port:       25
            encryption: ~
            username:   ~
            password:   ~
```

But you can also setup swift mailer to send the emails via PHPs `mail()` function. This would then use your configuration in `php.ini`:

```
all:
    mailer:
      class: sfMailer
      param:
        logging:           %SF_LOGGING_ENABLED%
        charset:           %SF_CHARSET%
        delivery_strategy: realtime
        transport:
          class: Swift_MailTransport
```

This and a lot more can be read in [More with Symfony - Chapter Emails](http://www.symfony-project.org/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/04-Emails) ;)

Comment: Thank you very much Felix. Once again, I am indebted to you. I made the change to the host parameter (so it matched my php.ini setting), and it worked.

Comment: @Stick it to THE MAN: It is always a pleasure to help :)

Comment: is it really necessary so setup php.ini?

Comment: @prongs: For sending the message? No, and I never said that. I was only talking about that the parameters of `php.ini` are used with a certain configuration. Have a look at the first code snippet, you just have to provide the address of your SMTP server there.

Comment: Well, I provided gmail smtp configuration and it's not working. I also tried with my other mail address but still not working. http://pastie.org/3020881  Can you help? the action code is the same as that of the OP.

Comment: for the second host, if I give encryption, it gives error `php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known` and if I leave it ~, it does not give any error but no email is received. Seems the error is in fsockopen

Comment: Where does `ENC_SSL` come from? The documentation suggests a different configuration for GMail: http://www.symfony-project.org/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/04-Emails#chapter_04_sub_sending_emails_via_gmail

Comment: oops...I took it from here http://www.symfony-project.org/cookbook/1_2/en/email . My bad. Still having problems with the other server

Answer (score 1):

I've managed email sending with Symfony 1.3.1.
I really don't know what's happening in your application, but here is my code and conf, that works great for me.

**Controller**:

```
<?php
... 
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
  ->setFrom('sender@foo.com')
  ->setTo('recipient@bar.com')
  ->setSubject('subject')
  ->setBody('body')
  ->setContentType('text/html');

$this->getMailer()->send($message);
...
```

**factories.yml**:

```
all:
  mailer:
    class: sfMailer
    param:
      delivery_strategy: spool
      spool_class:       Swift_FileSpool
      spool_arguments:   [/path/to/swift_spool]
```

Comment: Thanks for the snippet Darmen, I shall try that shortly (in the next few hours), and let you know if I have any success with that. Once again, thanks

Comment: Hi Darmen, I got it to work using Felix suggestion. I havent got round to trying your suggestion though - but I am sure it will work (I have voted it up). I will actually test it later on this weekedn time permiting.